# Chrome Remote Desktop: Windows Blank When Target Laptop Has Its Lid Closed

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, remote-access, lid, chrome-remote-desktop

I have this odd problem with Chrome Remote Desktop where when my target Windows 10 laptop has its lid closed, windows do not display properly(the windows display nothing):
[image: window that isn't displaying properly]

I did some [research](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234833-closing-laptop-lid-breaks-remote-control-program) and it appears by disabling `ACPI Lid` in Device Manager the problem is fixed, but might have some unintended side effects. How would I be able to fix this? Preferably without disabling any system devices.

FYI in the power settings, I set the laptop to do nothing when the lid is closed.

[related](https://superuser.com/questions/1568561/q-chrome-remote-desktop-showing-transparent-windows)

[another related question from the Google Support website](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/18864440/chrome-remote-desktop-unable-to-scroll-if-target-laptop-lid-is-down?hl=en)

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/640866/chrome-not-rendering-pages-on-a-remote-windows-8-laptop) and specifically disabling hardware acceleration on target.

Comment: I've seen similar answers online like this and was a bit skeptical. I'll try it.

Comment: @harrymc still no luck, I disabled hardware acceleration in Chrome and rebooted the laptop.

Comment: Try the other answers.

Comment: @harrymc should I disable hardware acceleration for specific programs that do not render?

Comment: If it helps only.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my problem is not just with a few applications not rendering correctly, parts of the Windows UI **also** look janky when my host laptop is closed.

Comment: The main program affected is Neovide(a Neovim GUI). Neovide does not appear to have a way to disable GPU acceleration. Though I could just simply use Neovim's TUI as I can still access Command Prompt.

Comment: Have you tried in GPO the combined settings of "sleep never" + "turn off display"?  Based on how you worded your question, I'm presuming you do want the display to turn off when you close the lid, but you want the running processes to stay alive and have remote access.  Normally, this use case works for when you want, e.g., downloads to continue after you close the lid, but I'm unsure how it behaves with remote access.  Worth a shot though?

Comment: I have not tried it in GPO. Perhaps that might work. I will test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too tried changing the ACPI lid to use the "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" but that didn't work. What did work was when I went to control panel - Device Manager - Display adapters then Right Clicked and selected 'Disable Device' for my display adapter.

This allowed me to use Chrome Remote Desktop with the lid closed.  I have a Dell Latitude 5520.

Comment: Wow! I can confirm this works like magic. I have a Lenovo running Windows 10 Pro.